# A short Clojure code returns wrong result

Tags: clojure

I'm running a short example code in the book "Web Development with Clojure":

```
(defn login [{:keys [id pass pass1] :as user}]
    (if (and id (= pass pass1))
        (println "valid user")
        (println user " is not filled in correctly")))
```

I tried :

```
(login {:keys ["tom" "123" "123"] :as "tom"})
```

and got:

```
{:as tom, :keys [tom 123 123]}  is not filled in correctly
nil
```

Why this result? The condition `(and id (= pass pass1))` is actually satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example uses [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc18), so it expects hashmap with keys `:id`, `:pass` and `pass1` as its single argument:

```
(login {:id "tom" :pass "123" :pass1 "123"})
```

## Update

I found a [blog post about destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html). It explains destructuring better than the official documentation.